# How do I attach a Hair piece to mesh so it moves with armature

Tags: mesh

I have these hair pieces on my mesh and I want them to be stuck to the headmesh for when I move the armature. I tried joining with control-J but I lost the hair. Is there anything else I can do?

[image]

Comment: Try parenting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be parenting the hairpiece mesh to the armature, with an Armature Modifier in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> menu. If the hair disappears, try toggling `Keep Transform` in the bottom-left options, and make sure the objects have their transforms (location/rotation/scale) applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> before parenting.

Automatic Weights should work, but you only want the head bone's influence. If Automatic Weights add more vertex groups than just the head, it would be simpler to just assign all vertices to the head bone's vertex group manually.

This will allow you to pose the armature and the hair mesh will follow the head, without merging the objects.

Comment: Hey I tried and this worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Boolean "UNION" Modifier?

Add Modifier, Boolean. In the drop down select Union, then eye dropper the Hair Mesh